# Unexpected dateInput behavior in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app with a `dateInput()` which is created with the following code:

```
dateInput(
          inputId = ns("mutatie_datum"),
          label = "Mutatiedatum:",
          value = "2019-12-01",
          format = "dd-M-yyyy",
          startview = "month",
          language = "nl"
        )
```

When I run the app, place the cursor in the `dateInput()` field and remove the 9 manually, my app crashes. Using `browser()` I can see that the value of the `dateInput()` has turned into `"0201-12-01"`. How can I prevent the app from performing calculations until a valid date is entered?

Answer (score 0):

`shiny` has some built-in functions to validate values. Below, I've used a combination of `validate`/`need` that shows an error message if the date is not valid. If you just want to stop the execution of the code without an error message, you could use `req` instead:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput(
    inputId = "mutatie_datum",
    label = "Mutatiedatum:",
    value = "2019-12-01",
    format = "dd-M-yyyy",
    startview = "month",
    language = "nl"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("test_out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  datum_fun <- reactive({
    # check the date
    validate(
      need(as.Date(input$mutatie_datum) > as.Date("2000-01-01"), "invalid date")
    )
    
    # do some calculations here
    input$mutatie_datum
  })
  output$test_out <- renderPrint({
    datum_fun()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @starja I'll try this!